# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at HTMLParagraphElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, django

I've been looking at this for ages and feel like I'm missing something obvious, any help much appreciated!

I'm trying to create nested accordions to represent a Django model in a convenient way. Paragraph elements are created and given ids using a Django for loop. Then JS is used to assign functionality (code below).

The title error points to the first id reference from this line, suggesting it is undefined.

```
if (acc2[i].id.slice(acc2[i].indexOf("_")+1) === acc3[j].id.slice(acc3[j].indexOf("_")+1))  {
```

However, using console.log I can get the expected values for these ids ("chain_name_1" and "chainseq_1" in the first iteration of the loop, when the error occurs). I can't figure out why they subsequently show up as undefined.

```
var acc2 = document.getElementsByClassName("prot_acc_2");
var acc3 = document.getElementsByClassName("prot_acc_3");
var i;
var j;

for (i = 0; i < acc2.length; i++) {
  acc2[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (j = 0; j < acc3.length; j++) {
      console.log(acc2[0].id)
      console.log(acc3[0].id)
      var content = acc3[j];
      if (acc2[i].id.slice(acc2[i].indexOf("_")+1) === acc3[j].id.slice(acc3[j].indexOf("_")+1))  {
          if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
          }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you are using `i` in your event listener but `i` is defined in the "global" scope and does not have the value that you think it does. It will have the value of `acc2.length` which is one greater than the maximum index of `acc2` and so `acc2[i]` will always return `undefined`

You should use `this` in place of `acc2[i]` in your event handler as it will be equal to the element clicked

```
for (i = 0; i < acc2.length; i++) {
  acc2[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (j = 0; j < acc3.length; j++) {
      var content = acc3[j];
      if (this.id.slice(this.id.indexOf("_") + 1) === acc3[j].id.slice(acc3[j].id.indexOf("_") + 1))  {
          if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
          }
      }
    }
  });
}
```